# Wordpress running on AppEngine: Photos not showing

Tags: php, google-app-engine, wordpress, google-cloud-storage

I have a wordpress site running on AppEngine. I followed http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/

I deactivated billing a few times before. So my site was inactive for some time. Now that I've booted it back up again, I am unable to upload photos- well, I've checked the bucket and it shows up there (with a different file name - a really long string of nonsense like this lkeEFJj234dsfsdfFJSLDFdhd). I could see the photos in Wordpress before and those uploads show up with the same file name as the file I uploaded from my computer in the Bucket.

So it uploads to the bucket, but wordpress can't see it? Maybe because of the different filename? Or can this be an effect of me deactivating my site for a while? I can still see the uploads I made before when it was still working (in wordpress, they're still in the media viewer thing).

The bat cache thing and the app engine plug in are both installed and activated (latest version).

I've tried creating a new bucket, no luck as well...

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem in the App Engine plugin.  If you look in the issues in the github starter project, you will see an issue for it.  I submitted a pull request/issue here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-wordpress-plugin/issues/16

If you feel up to it you can change the following:

The lines that appear to be causing the issue are in /modules/uploads.php, 195-196

```
$_COOKIE[$auth_cookie_name] = $auth_cookie;
$_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE] = $logged_in_cookie;
```

If these are changed to the following code, the upload works

```
if ( !isset($_COOKIE[$auth_cookie_name]) ) $_COOKIE[$auth_cookie_name] = $auth_cookie;
if ( !isset($_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE]) ) $_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE] = $logged_in_cookie;
```